# How can a NPM Package depends on tests in another package but injects its own exports to be tested?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, mocha.js

Ok, I’m not sure if this is possible but here goes,
Let’s say I’m the central weather monitor for the entire world.
I need to be able to call every countries weather API to get information like temperature, wind and rain fall.
All the countries got together and agreed that there packages will export the same functions.
So every country builds a NPM package that has:

```
exports.currentTemp() { return <current temperature>;}
exports.currentWind() { return <current wind speed>;}
exports.currentRain() { return <current rain fall>;}
```

The central weather monitoring has created a test suite call weather-api-test and it runs some tests.
It is each countries responsibility to make sure there code is passing the tests before pushing code.
How can each country depend on the weather-api-test package and run there tests?
I guess a short way to ask this would be, how can I dynamically add a require(‘uk-weather-api’); into mocha tests?

Comment: I have created a bad example here:https://github.com/MikeBateman/global-weather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a library called rewire that may allow you to do what you want here.
It essentially allows you to override local variables in other scripts.

https://github.com/jhnns/rewire

For example:
If your shared test (lets call it theirTest) requires a script like this:

```
var foo = require( "theirScript" );
```

You can use rewire in your own test like this:

```
var rewire = require("rewire");
var theirTest = rewire( "./theirTest" ); // Note that I used rewire here and not require
var bar = require("./myScript"); // The script you want to inject into their tests

theirTest.__set__("foo", bar); //__set__ is a rewire injected function allowing you to access foo
```

What you end up with is your own new test script that simply injects your script into their tests. In which case you're running their tests against your script.

Comment: Thanks mitch, the rewire library seems to fit perfectly, I have created git repo https://github.com/MikeBateman/global-weather and will look to build out my example for others. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could have your test suite load a module named `./impl` that people who want to run your suite against their implementation would create so as to load their specific implementation and make it available to your test suite. The suite could be like this:

```
var assert = require("assert");
var impl;

try {
    impl = require("./impl");
}
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error && e.code === "MODULE_NOT_FOUND")
        throw new Error("You must create a module that loads as `./impl` in" +
                        "in the test suite so that the suite can load your " +
                        "implementation of the API.");

    // Just rethrow anything else...
    throw e;
}

it("works", function () {
    assert(impl.getId() !== undefined);
});
```

Suppose I have an implementation in `a.js`:

```
exports.getId = function () {
    return module.id;
};
```

I can create an `impl.js` file like this to load my implementation:

```
module.exports = require("./a");
```

Comment: Hi Louis, I wanted to say thanks for your suggestion but I felt that Mitch’s solution using rewire is a better because its more SOILD, no need to create ‘./impl’.